# Can't use PROGMEM attribute with non - const variables

Tags: microcontroller, atmega

In an ATmega32, I intend to use the program memory for writing too but I am getting a

```
variable 'var' must be const in order to be put into read-only section by means of '__attribute__((progmem))'
```

error. The reason I thought I can use the program memory for writing too is that the SPM instruction is supported in the device I am using. So would you have any suggestions why I am getting this error and what can do to use the program memory for writing too? Thank you very much.

Best regards

Comment: and the device your programming is?

Comment: @JIm Dearden I updated the question.

Comment: The only way to write to flash on AVR is the hard way. Don't expect the compiler to help.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams Thank you. But may I ask: 1) Why is compiler support not available for this task? 2) What exactly is _the_ _hard_ _way_? How much of the work do I need to do in assembly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SPM` instruction or not, program memory uses flash memory technology, which requires a fairly elaborate procedure to erase and write new data. There's no compiler that going to let you treat it as ordinary RAM by simply allocating variables there.

You can store data there, but it will always be through library routines that hide the complexity. Going through the library API also emphasizes the fact that this is data that you don't want to be changing very often, because you don't want to prematurely exceed the wear limits on the flash memory.

Comment: I see. So writing to flash memory is discouraged on intention with the purpose of not exceeding the write limit of it right? So does this mean that if I am in need of large memory space (> 3000 bytes), then I am out of luck?

Comment: It depends on what you need the space for. If you're building something like a datalogger, in which you write large amounts of data sequentially, it's fine. But if you need a large number of ordinary variables that get updated frequently (e.g., counters), then it's a bad idea. For that, you really need to select a processor that has more RAM to begin with. In a pinch, you can add an external RAM chip, but that gets messy unless the processor has direct support for an external memory bus.

Comment: I see. Thank you and everybody very much for your kind replies.

Answer (score 0):

FLASH memory is not intended for write access from application, i.e. using {SPM} command. The instruction may be used only if running code bootloader code to reflash main (or even bootloader) application. But it's low level command without any support in C code. Even reading from flash you need via {LPM} (or higher C functions). Hence using {PROGMEM} without {const} makes no sense and compiler reports message.